# Parse a website after POST request with Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to scrap some addresses off of a store locator for a website to make it easier to put into google maps and see where all the stores in my state are located.

Here is the store locator website:
http://www.rockyboots.com/locator

When I go here, I put in my state, and it returns all the addresses. I am wondering how to do this with python, specifically the Requests module.

I tried to reverse engineer what information was being sent when I submitted the form, and got

```
form = {'dwfrm_storelocator_address_states_stateUSCA':'NS', 
        'dwfrm_storelocator_findbystate':'Search'}
```

so my request currently looks like:

```
r = requests.post(url, data = form)
```

where

```
url = 'http://www.rockyboots.com/locator'
```

This seems to just give me the locator page again, not the submitted form page.

At this point, I am just not sure what else to do or try, so any info would be helpful. This is just a side project that I could use to learn some web scraping.

Comment: sometimes the request headers matter too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user on Reddit ([commandlineluser](https://www.reddit.com/user/commandlineluser)) helped me with the solution. Turns out, there was another parameter that had to be passed to the POST request, but that parameter changed every time you access the URL.

[The final solution is shown here.](https://gist.github.com/wesleybowman/b312b18781e5cc1a6721eda0cd98d1cd)